# templateUrl resource load does not work using webpack

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack

I am starting building a personal project using Angular 2 / Typescript / Webpack (I am using node v6.2.1)

I can not load a template as external resource using the 'templateUrl' property.

Below, a hello world project which reproduce the issue and the error output:

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "angular2-whatafuck",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "NODE_ENV=development webpack -d --progress",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server  --progress --colors --port 3100 --    inline",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "author": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/forms": "0.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-alpha.7",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.12",
    "angular2-moment": "^0.8.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.0-beta.9",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.13.0",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.3",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.3",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "ts-loader": "^0.8.2",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings": "^1.3.0",
    "webpack": "^1.13.1"
  }
}
```

My main.ts (entry point)

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
require('zone.js/dist/zone');
import { bootstrap }    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

bootstrap(<any>AppComponent);
```

My app.component.ts (hello world component)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: require('./app.component.html')
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

My app.component.html (hello world template)

```
<h1>My First Angular 3 App</h1>
```

My index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<my-app>Loading...</my-app>
<script src="js/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
var BrowserSyncPlugin = require('browser-sync-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {

  entry: {
    main: "./src/main.ts", //main app entry point
  },
  output: {
    //filename: './app/js/bundle.js'
    path: __dirname,
    filename: "./app/js/bundle.js"
  },
  resolve: {
     extensions: ['' , '.js' , '.ts']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.ts?$/, loader: 'ts-loader' , exclude: /node_modules/ },
      {test: /\.html$/, loader: 'html'}
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new BrowserSyncPlugin({
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 3000,
      proxy: 'http://localhost:3100/app/', 
    })
  ]
}
```

Console error stack: (snippet)

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not    Found)    http://localhost:3000/app/%3Ch1%3EMy%20First%20Angular%203%20App%3C/h1%3E
bundle.js:55829EXCEPTION: Failed to load     %3Ch1%3EMy%20First%20Angular%203%20App%3C/h1%3E
bundle.js:55820EXCEPTION: Failed to load     %3Ch1%3EMy%20First%20Angular%203%20App%3C/h1%3EBrowserDomAdapter.logError @     bundle.js:55820
bundle.js:55829EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Failed to load     %3Ch1%3EMy%20First%20Angular%203%20App%3C/h1%3E
bundle.js:55820EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Failed to load     %3Ch1%3EMy%20First%20Angular%203%20App%3C/h1%3EBrowserDomAdapter.logError @     bundle.js:55820
bundle.js:55820STACKTRACE:BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ bundle.js:55820
bundle.js:55820Error: Uncaught (in promise): Failed to load     %3Ch1%3EMy%20First%20Angular%203%20App%3C/h1%3E
```

Clearly is trying to load a wrong resource http://localhost:3000/app/%3Ch1%3EMy%20First%20Angular%203%20App%3C/h1%3E. This looks totally wrong. It should be included in the bundle and required by Webpack and NOT as external resource. But I could not find a proper solution. I am not sure if something in Webpack is missconfigured or in Angular 2.

It works if I use an inline template in the component with the "template" property.

Any help will be appreciated.

Cheers,
  Vicens

Comment: You shouldn't use `require` if you're using `templateUrl`. Just provide the path to the template as a string instead. Or, better yet, use `template` along with `require`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by [powerbuoy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38038345/templateurl-resource-load-does-not-work-using-webpack#comment63516693_38038345), the `templateUrl` property should refer to a path string, e.g. `'./app.component.html'`.

If you want to inline the html with `require`, you can try using

```
template: require('./app.component.html')
```

Note the difference between `templateUrl` and `template`:

`template`: Should be a HTML string, either inline or loaded from an external file

`templateUrl`: Should be a path to your external HTML template

Comment: that is the proper answer. It was in front of my nose and I was blind! thanks @Michel

Comment: hero! Key difference between template & templateUrl when using a raw loader

Answer (score 1):

try `template: require('!raw!./app.component.html')`

In my webpack config, I use raw-loader to load .html file so I just need to `template: require('./app.component.html')`. It may also work for you, but I have no experience with html-loader to confirm that.

Comment: Hi @Can, Thanks for your support! Unfortunately it did not work. The error change slightly (now requesting for this resource: Cannot GET /app/module.exports%20=%20%22%3Ch1%3EMy%20First%20Angular%203%20App%3C/h1%3E%22;) But basically the same issue is still there: Requesting a resource that it should not be requested.

Comment: That's strange. Did you double check that you actually use **template:** , not templateUrl ??